# Powershell install Java silently

Tags: java, powershell

I need to install new Java update silently. I have these arguments for installation:

```
INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=0 SPONSORS=0
```

and I tried:

```
Start-Process -Wait '\\srv\netlogon\java\jre-8u45-windows-i586.exe' -ArgumentList '/s INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=0 SPONSORS=0'
```

and also:

```
$arguments = @(
    '/s',
    "/v/qn `"INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=0 SPONSORS=0 /L \`"c:\temp\java_install.log\`"`""
)

$proc = Start-Process "\\srv\netlogon\java\jre-8u45-windows-i586.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru
if($proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    Throw "ERROR"
}
```

and both version has prompt dialog. How to install it silently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution in cmdLet `Execute-Process` via this [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Install-Java-within-an-4daea195). Works fine!

And calling it:

```
Execute-Process '\\srv\java\jre-8u45-windows-x64.exe' -Arguments '/s INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=0 SPONSORS=0 /L c:\temp\jre-8u45-windows-x64.log'
```

Comment: The link is now dead; here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20200318062740/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Install-Java-within-an-4daea195 but the download link there doesn't work, and it's unclear where `Execute-Process` comes from (it's not a built-in cmdlet).

Answer (score 2):

The option you pass to the installer are only valid for an [installation configuration file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#config_file_options). If you do not want to use a configuration file you can use the following command line options for a [silent install](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml).

Comment: I think, there is problem with domain security settings (UAC), but cannot google it (solution).

Answer (score -1):

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12